# Django strange behaviour when an exception occurs, using django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing some REST api for a webservice.
Starting from some days I've experienced a big problem that is blocking me.
When the code has an exception (during developing) the django server respond only after 5/8 or 10 minutes... with the error that occurs.

To understand what is happening I've started the server in debug using pycharm.... and then clicking on pause during the big waiting.. the code is looping here into python2.7/SocketServer.py

```py
def _eintr_retry(func, *args):
    """restart a system call interrupted by EINTR"""
    while True:
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except (OSError, select.error) as e:
            if e.args[0] != errno.EINTR:
                raise
    print(foo)
```

What can I do? I'm pretty desperate!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: What is that error?

Comment: every error... a mandatory field empty.. whatever.. the problem is not linked to the error but to che SocketServer looping for minutes

Comment: Is there any way to reproduce that? Did you check on any other environment? I mean any other os, virtualenv etc.. .

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that happens in Django debug mode because Django generates a nice page with traceback and a list of all local variables for every stack frame.

When Django models has an inefficient `__str__` (`__unicode__` since you're using Python 2) method, this can result in Django loading many thousands of objects from the database to display traceback.

In my experience this is the only reason for a very long pauses on exception in Django. Try running with `DEBUG = False` or check what exactly model has inefficient `__str__` method that hits database.